# Increasing the ThreadStackSize to solve "jmeter.control.GenericController: StackOverflowError detected" error

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

I am getting this error: "jmeter.control.GenericController: StackOverflowError detected" when I run my test. I am not able to understand why i'm getting this error.

I read a similar question on JMeter's forum where someone has suggested to increase the ThreadStackSize to 4096. I'm running the test in Jmeter's GUI mode. Where exactly should I change the ThreadStackSize? Is there some file in Jmeter's /bin directory where I can change this property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into your JMETER_HOME/bin dir, find there either `jmeter` file (unix shell - in case you are working with any unix/linux) or `jmeter.bat` (windows bat-file - in case you are using windows os).
In both your can find strings like:

`HEAP="-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
NEW="-XX:NewSize=128m -XX:MaxNewSize=128m"
TENURING="-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=2"
RMIGC="-Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=600000"
PERM="-XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"
DUMP="-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"
SERVER="-server"
ARGS="$SERVER $DUMP $HEAP $NEW $SURVIVOR $TENURING $EVACUATION $RMIGC $PERM"
java $ARGS $JVM_ARGS -jar dirname $0/ApacheJMeter.jar "$@"`

that define values of jmeter's JVM params.

Simply add **-XX:ThreadStackSize=4096** to any of these variables like

`ARGS="$SERVER $DUMP $HEAP $NEW $SURVIVOR $TENURING $EVACUATION $RMIGC $PERM -XX:ThreadStackSize=4096"
java $ARGS $JVM_ARGS -jar dirname $0/ApacheJMeter.jar "$@"`

or even

`java $ARGS $JVM_ARGS -XX:ThreadStackSize=4096 -jar dirname $0/ApacheJMeter.jar "$@"`

and restart your jmeter instance.

Comment: also, can you please check out this query I had put up related to using parameters in CSV dataset config's file name?
[link] (http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3441/using-a-variable-in-the-filename-textfield-of-csv-dataset-config)
It would be great if you could suggest me some solution to it.